# Auto resize the widths of JTable's columns dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with 3 columns:

```
- No. #
- Name
- PhoneNumber
```

I want to make specific width for each column as follows:

[image]

and I want the JTable able to update the widths of its columns dynamically if needed (for example, inserting large number in the column `#`) and keeping same style of the JTable

I solved the first issue, using this code:

```
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnNumber).setPreferredWidth(columnWidth);
```

but I didn't success to make myTable to update the widths dynamically ONLY if the current width of the column doesn't fit its contents. Can you help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here I found my answer: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/
The idea is to check some rows' content length to adjust the column width.
In the article, the author provided a full code in a downloadable java file.

```
JTable table = new JTable( ... );
table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );

for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++)
{
    TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
    int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth();

    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
    {
        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        Component c = table.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
        preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);

        //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

        if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
        {
            preferredWidth = maxWidth;
            break;
        }
    }

    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the addRow(...) method of the DefaultTableModel to add data to the table dynamically.

Update:

To adjust the width of a visible column I think you need to use:

```
tableColumn.setWidth(...);
```

Comment: oops, I want to make JTable update the widths dynamically, but I wrote to make the JTable be updated dynamically, sorry

Comment: Incidentally, the accepted answer is actually yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

I actually run into this problem too. I've found one useful link that solved my issue.
Pretty much get the specific column and set its setMinWidth and setMaxWidth to be the same(as fixed.)

```
private void fixWidth(final JTable table, final int columnIndex, final int width) {
    TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
    column.setMinWidth(width);
    column.setMaxWidth(width);
    column.setPreferredWidth(width);
}
```

Ref: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1353172