# Make all columns narrower in Matlab Variables editor

Tags: matlab

I often use openvar('myArrayName') to browse my data.  However, I got spoiled by Excel's ability to narrow all columns at once, allowing me to see lots of data.  It's very stifling to use the limited bit of desktop space that I have to peer at so few columns at once.  Manually adjusting each column is not a good solution because I'm constantly opening up variables, and they often have many columns.  Is there a way to narrow the columns in a bulk manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but can get you started. The basic idea is to first [get a handle to underlying java table](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/variables-editor-scrolling#solution), and then resize all columns, e.g. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454700/5540279). You can download [TableColumnAdjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) java class, package it into a jar and load using `javaclasspath`. When searching for a java handle using `findjobj`, note that table class will depend on the type of the variable you are trying to display (some examples [here](https://github.com/okomarov/scrollto/blob/master/scrollto.m)), so we need to find the right handle.

```
javaaddpath('path\to\TableColumnAdjuster.jar');
my_var= randn(1e4,10);
openvar('my_var');
resizevar('my_var');

function resizevar(name)
    desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance();
    varclient = desktop.getClient(name);
    jh = findjobj(varclient);
    hNames = get(jh, 'Name');
    validNames = {'VariableTable','CellTable','DatasetVariableTable','TableObjectVariableTable','CategoricalVariableTable','TimeSeriesArrayEditorTablePanel:fDataTable'};
    jTable = jh(find(ismember(hNames, validNames),1));

    jTable.setAutoGrowthTemporarilyDisabled(true);
    jTable.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    pause(0.1);

    spacing = 10;
    tca = TableColumnAdjuster(jTable, spacing);
    tca.adjustColumns();
end
```

The problem is that Matlab will keep updating the table as you scroll and/or underlying data changes, which may reset the width (or even have other side-effects like adding more empty columns etc). If you explore the custom table class used by Matlab, you will notice a handy `setAutoGrowthTemporarilyDisabled` method. Setting that to `true` allows us to temporarily avoid these side-effects (`pause` seems to be required for it to take effect), however columns may still be resized once you start interacting with table/data. You would need to explore this custom table class further to see how this can be prevented.

Comment: Thanks, nirvana-msu.  I'm guessing that there is no magic way to get around a programmatic solution that dives under the hood of the GUI.  I won't be doing that any time soon (the reality of my time situation), but knowing that this is in fact the situation is useful.  I'll wait a bit for a magic ready-made solution, and if none surfaces, I'll mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: Great question. Sounds like something they should implement.